# How do I get my JButton to both switch the JPanel and close the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I've managed to get the JButton buttonOne in class Database to switch panels, but at the same time it's opening a new JFrame to do this. How can I change it so it just changes the JFrame panel without having to open another JFrame? I have a feeling I could do this if I could return both JPanel and JFrame but I don't know how to do so. Thanks for any help :

First class, with the JFrame and the JPanel that is being switched to on click of 'buttonOne' :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDatabaseFarme;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Database{

    //Running the GUI
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Database gui2 = new Database();
        gui2.mainPanel();
    }


     JDatabaseFarme mainPanel() throws IOException {

        // GridBagLayout/Constraint
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,15,15,15);

        final JDatabaseFarme DatabaseFarme = new JDatabaseFarme("Lohn Jocke and the Quest for Qualia"); //Had to set DatabaseFarme to final for the action listener
        //JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); (??)

        final JComponent panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("res/FinalBG.png")))); //Had to set panel to final for the action listener
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        ////// Creating JButtons/Icons for the buttons ////
        BufferedImage buttonIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("res/PlayGame.png"));
        JButton button = new JButton ("", new ImageIcon(buttonIcon));

        BufferedImage buttonIcon2 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Scoreboard.png"));
        JButton buttonTwo = new JButton ("", new ImageIcon(buttonIcon2));

        BufferedImage buttonIcon3 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/SQLs.png"));
        JButton buttonThree = new JButton ("",new ImageIcon(buttonIcon3));

        // Scoreboard button ActionListener
        buttonThree.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                        //removed some code from here 
                        try {
                            panel.setVisible(false);
                            SQLsPanel a = new SQLsPanel(); 
                            JComponent SQLsPanel = a.SQLsPanel();
                            DatabaseFarme.add(SQLsPanel);
                            DatabaseFarme.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, SQLsPanel);
                            SQLsPanel.setVisible(true);

                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                                }

                });

        ////// Creating/adding button rollover images /////

        BufferedImage buttonIcon1b = ImageIO.read(new File("res/PlayGameHigh.png"));
        button.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon1b));

        BufferedImage buttonIcon2b = ImageIO.read(new File("res/ScoreboardHigh.png"));
        buttonTwo.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon2b));

        BufferedImage buttonIcon3b = ImageIO.read(new File("res/SQLsHigh.png"));
        buttonThree.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonIcon3b));

        // Setting up GridBagConstraints for each JButton
        gbc.weightx=1;
        gbc.weighty=0;
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

        panel.add(button, gbc); //PLAY GAME

        gbc.weightx=1;
        gbc.weighty=0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=1;

        panel.add(buttonTwo,gbc); //SCOREBOARD

        gbc.weightx=1;
        gbc.weighty=0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=2;

        panel.add(buttonThree,gbc); //SQLS

        // JDatabaseFarme settings
        DatabaseFarme.add(panel);
        DatabaseFarme.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
        DatabaseFarme.setSize(860,500);
        DatabaseFarme.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        DatabaseFarme.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDatabaseFarme.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DatabaseFarme.setResizable(false);
        DatabaseFarme.setVisible(true);

        // JButton icon details 
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);


        buttonTwo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonTwo.setContentAreaFilled(false);


        buttonThree.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonThree.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        return DatabaseFarme;
        }
}
```

My second class, it contains the JButton that needs to change panel and close the JDatabaseFarme :

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDatabaseFarme;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SQLsPanel {



 JComponent SQLsPanel() throws IOException {

        final JComponent SQLsPanel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("res/HowToPlayBG.png"))));  

        SQLsPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        BufferedImage buttonOneIcon = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Database.png"));
        JButton buttonOne = new JButton("",new ImageIcon(buttonOneIcon));

        BufferedImage buttonOneIconB = ImageIO.read(new File("res/DatabaseHigh.png"));
        buttonOne.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(buttonOneIconB));

        buttonOne.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                SQLsPanel.setVisible(false);
                try {

                    Database passme = new Database();
                    JDatabaseFarme DatabaseFarmeA = passme.mainPanel();
                    DatabaseFarmeA.add(SQLsPanel);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                        }

        });

        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets = new Insets(15,15,15,15);
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;
        SQLsPanel.add(buttonOne, gbc);

        buttonOne.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        buttonOne.setContentAreaFilled(false);

        return SQLsPanel;   


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lohn Jocke and the Quest for Qualia"); //Had to set frame to     final for the action listener
    final String name = frame.getName();
```

Add the variable 'name' just below where you declare the JFrame.

```
      // JFrame settings
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
    frame.setSize(860,500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    if(Frame.getFrames().length > 1){
        Frame[] f = Frame.getFrames();
                for(Frame frames : f){
            if(!frames.getName().equals(name)){
                frames.dispose();
            }
            }
    }
```

Add this below where you set the JFrame settings.

what happens is when you call this

```
   MainMenu passme = new MainMenu();
```

From the InstructionsPanel you are creating a new JFrame from your class constructor in addition to the current frame you already have(Hence why you end up with 2). what I have tried to do is get the name of your new Frame you are creating(with the name variable), then using the loop at the bottom wipe all other Frames away leaving you with the new one with which to display your Panel.(Frame.getFrames() returns a list of all frames, I then iterate over removing all the ones that aren't needed)

You may want to tweak it if you add more JFrames in future but hopefully this will be somewhat effective for you for now at least.(i have tried to replicate your code with dummy images to grasp at the problem for this 'fix' so apologies if I have misunderstood the issue here )

Hope this helps.